# Finding value of $\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)$ when tangent and quadrant is given

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot figure out how to do this problem. It is a problem in my textbook but there is no answer to it. Do you mind helping me?

Within the range of $0 \leq θ \leq 2π$, if $\tan \theta = -3$ and $\sin \theta <0$, find the exact value of $\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note first that since $\sin\theta$ is negative, and $\tan\theta$ is negative, it follows that $\cos\theta$ is positive. Thus $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant. It follows that $\theta/2$ is in the second quadrant, and therefore $\cos(\theta/2)$ is negative.

We use the cosine double-angle identity, which you probably have seen in the form 
$\cos(2t)=2\cos^2 t-1$. Putting $t=\theta/2$, we get
$$\cos \theta=2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1.\tag{1}$$
We calculate $\cos\theta$. The identity $\sec^2\theta=\tan^2\theta+1$ is useful here. From it we get that $\sec^2\theta=10$. It follows that $\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{10}$. Since $\cos\theta$ is positive, we have $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Now we use (1). We have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1$. Thus
$$\cos^2(\theta/2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right).\tag{2}$$

Now, if we recall that $\cos(\theta/2)$ is negative, we can use (2) to find $\cos(\theta/2)$.

**Remark:** The identity $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$ may be unfamiliar to you. It can be obtained from $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ by dividing both sides by $\cos^2\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Pythagoras' theorem and the following information about trigonometric functions
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}},\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$
to find $\cos\theta$.

Then use the double angle formula to find $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ by considering
$$\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the info separately. Is $\sin \theta < 0$, then $\theta$ must be in the third or fourth quadrant, think of the unit circle drawing. But, on the other side, if $\tan \theta = -3 < 0$, then $\theta$ has to be on the second, or fourth quadrant. The only possibility that satisfies both cases is: $\theta$ **is on the fourth quadrant**. This tell us that $\frac{3 \pi}{2} \leq \theta < 2 \pi$, so we have $\frac{3 \pi}{4} \leq \frac{\theta}{2} < \pi$, so that means $\frac{\theta}{2}$ is on the second quadrant. So, after we find the absolute value of $\cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)$, we know that it must be negative. And, apparently, there's no way to find the **exact** value of that cosine, because $\mathrm{arctan} (-3)$ is not a special angle. Some not too intuitive trigonometric expressions are: $$\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}} \qquad \qquad \tan^2\theta = \frac{1 - \cos(2 \theta)}{1 + \cos(2\theta)}$$
Sure, the second formula gives us $\tan^2\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right) = \dfrac{1 - \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})}{1 + \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}$, and you could solve for $\cos (\frac{\theta}{2})$, but I don't think it would help much, becaus of that $\tan$, which probably can be written in terms of info we don't have, only. [Also, Wolfram Alpha gives an horrible decimal expansion as answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28arctan%28-3%29/2%29), which makes me wonder if there really is way to solve this.